# "Miss to inform" or "fail to inform"

Tags: grammar

Do you *miss to inform* someone or *fail to inform* them? I am seeing *miss* appear in places but it just seems awkward.

Comment: I don't think it's *miss to inform* but rather *misinform* , which is a verb and means *to give someone false or inaccurate information.*

Answer (score 9):

"Misinform" is typically used to refer to an instance in which you provide *incorrect* information.

"Fail to inform" would refer to an instance in which you *do not* provide information at all.

A quick survey of Google results indicates that all uses of "miss to inform" are the result of what appears to be poor translation, which would be in keeping with my own observations — I've never heard the phrase used by a native speaker or in any context that wasn't garbled Engrish or equivalent.

Comment: Any source of your answer? please

Comment: I can add to the above by saying that a source for this answer is a lifetime of speaking English. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

When the verb "miss" takes a clausal complement, it is a gerund (form in *-ing*), not an infinitive.

So *missed informing him* is possible, though rather less likely than *failed to inform him*. But **missed to inform him* is not something that a native English speaker would say.

The verb *miss* in this way has an implication that the person who missed it expected or planned for it to happen. So *I missed informing him* has a strong implication that this was something I specifically intended to do, but something happened to stop me; whereas *I failed to inform him* doesn't have that implication: I might have intended to, or I might never have intended to (though presumably *somebody* thought I would do so, or I wouldn't have occasion to say this!).