# Can “missed” be followed by “to”?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english

I got a text which had me thinking about the use of the verb "to miss"

> The workpaper is incomplete as I missed to consider a criteria.

Is the above sentence correct? Is "I missed to consider" grammatically correct?

Comment: Idiomatically "I missed considering..." vs "I forgot to consider..."

Comment: A century or two ago, most Anglophones were quite happy to say *He did this, but **he omitted to do that***. But not many would endorse that usage today.

Comment: _Miss_ takes a gerund complement, not an infinitive. _To_ is the complementizer that identifies the verb phrase of an infinitive clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Miss to inform" or "fail to inform"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69897/miss-to-inform-or-fail-to-inform) ... 'When the verb "miss" takes a clausal complement, it is a gerund (form in -ing), not an infinitive.' [@Colin Fine]

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. Here are a few alternatives that do make sense and communicate the same idea:

- The workpaper is incomplete as I **failed** to consider the **criteria**
- The workpaper is incomplete as I **did not see the** criteria
- The workpaper is incomplete as I **forgot to consider the** criteria

*Note: criteria is the plural of criterion. This is another modification I have implemented into this answer.*

Answer (score 0):

*Miss* can mean *fail to hit* ("I threw the packet away but missed the wastepaper basket") or *regret the absence of* ("I miss you." "I miss sitting out in the garden now the weather is cold.")

Better verbs for leaving out something you should have done are *forgot, omitted* or *failed*, which can all be used with the infinitive *to [verb].*